# Why setVisible doesn't work?

Tags: java, swing, gif, layout-manager, border-layout

I have a swing GUI with border layout. in the `NORTH` I have added some component.
My label component which has GIF icon is invisible `lblBusy.setVisible(false);`
later a button make it visible like below. Why it does not show up?

```
btnDownload.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lblBusy.setVisible(true);
                    btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

            download = new Download(txtSource.getText(), new File(txtDestination.getText()), textAreaStatus);
            download.start();
            lblBusy.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: How did you add your components in the `NORTH` area? If you added them individually, one after another, only the last one will be available, so maybe your label wasn't really added to your panel?

Comment: ** Like this:** `  constraints.setGxGyGwGhWxWyFillAnchor(4, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, TGridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, TGridBagConstraints.EAST);
  gridbaglayout.setConstraints(lblBusy, constraints);
  panelStatus.add(lblBusy);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) this is `EventDispatchThread` rellated issue, EDT quite guaranteed that all changes to the GUI would be done on one moment

2) you invoked `ActionPerformed` from `JButton`, and untill all events ended your GUI should be freeze or is unresponsible, same for `JButton` and `JLabel` in your case

3) better would be redirect reading for `File` contents to the Backgroung task e.g. `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread` then `JButton` and `JLabel` will be changed and GUI would be during Background task responsible for Mouse or KeyBoard

or

4) dirty hack split to the two separated `Action` delayed by `javax.swing.Timer`, but in this case again untill all events ended your GUI will be  freeze or is unresponsible

Comment: +1 for the info. If i am not mistake at point 3 (JButton and JLabel will be changed and GUI would be during), i guess you mean to write GUI would be doing instead of GUI would be during during. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Most probably because the GUI was packed at a time the label was not visible, so no space was assigned to display it.  For anything more definite, post an SSCCE.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are writing `lblBusy.setVisible(true);` and after that `lblBusy.setVisible(false);` in the mouseClicked() method. Since you wanted to make it visible at the click of a button aren't you be using only `lblBusy.setVisible(true);`, instead of using both.

You can call `lblBusy.setVisible(false);` from the end of  your Download Class though, once it's done doing what it does.

Regards